# Dropdown option open in new tab Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

It opens in the same tab itself. I want to redirect to next tab or next window.

Code:

```
try
{   
    for(int i=1;i<=9;i++)
    {
        if(i==1)
        {
            System.out.println("No Condition applied");
        }
        else if(i==2)
        {
            WebElement menu2=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/ul/li["+i+"]/a"));
            Actions action=new Actions(driver);
            //It opens in same page
            action.moveToElement(menu2).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[2]/ul/li["+i+"]/a"))).click().build().perform();
            //mouse hover on selected drop down
            action.moveToElement(menu2).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[2]/ul/li["+i+"]/a"))).build().perform();
            //Should open in New Tab-But Not working
            action.moveToElement(menu2).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[2]/ul/li["+i+"]/a"))).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Menu button not found");
}
```

Comment: Please post a link to the page and describe (in words, not code) what you are attempting. Right now it's difficult to understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Actions` class for that

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[2]/ul/li["+i+"]/a"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).click(element).keyUp(Keys.SHIFT).build().perform();
```

As a side note, don't use absolute `xpath`, it fragile. Try to use `id`/`class` attributes as much as you can.

Comment: Here I Am using 2 x-path menu2 is the DropDown heading then one more x-path is the DropDown value. So how can directly call DropDown value without DropDown heading

Comment: @AshwinRaj What do you mean *call DropDown value without DropDown heading*? and what is the connection to what you asked in the question?

Comment: As per your instruction I used the above actions class but i didn't get the output